# WPF DataGrid/List custom sorting and criteria

Tags: c#, list, wpfdatagrid

Ok I have some data in a List which is then Bound to a DataGrid. The Data looks similar to this.

```
    Code Product     Weight
    008  811         10.0
    008  842         12.0
    I008 852         8.0
    008  N/A         0.0
    I008 ALL Version 0.516
    VAL  N/A         1.0
```

How do I sort this based on the following rules

- Anything in Product that = N/A must go to the top
- Anything in Code that starts with the letter I goes to the bottom
- Anything else just sort by Code

So the above table would like this.

```
    Code Product     Weight
    008  N/A         0.0
    VAL  N/A         1.0
    008  811         10.0
    008  842         12.0
    I008 852         8.0
    I008 ALL Version 0.516
```

Answer (score 0):

Without going through hoops and writing your own sorting algorithm, I would just pre-query the data ORDERED BY the condition you ultimately want to present.

If from MySQL, you can use the IF()...  If from others like SQL-Server, you may have to substitute to using CASE WHEN / ELSE END

```
SELECT 
      pr.Code,
      pr.Product,
      pr.Weight
   from
      ProductTable pr
   order by
      if( pr.Product = 'N/A', 1, 2 ),
      if( LEFT( pr.Code, 1 ) = 'I', 2, 1 ),
      pr.Code
```

Comment: even with using ORDERED BY I think I still have to do some messing around. As its coming form an SQL database I think I may add another column to it and call it priority or something and then loop through the database and mark anything with Product = N/A as 1, Anything with an 'I' as 3 and then anything else as 2. Then just do ORDERED BY on the priority field.

Comment: @Gazlar, you can do complex ordering in SQL, which SQL are you using... MySQL, SQL-Server, ???

Comment: I'm using SQLCE as the database and Linq to do any query etc.

Comment: Is there a Linq way of doing what you wrote DRapp?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help in that department... I don't Linq... (yet)

Answer (score 0):

You could right your own sorting algorithm.

Usually C# has several interfaces that you can implement like IComparable or IEquatable that are used by methods like Array.Sort() to sort an array or a collection.

Cheers,
Felipe